# angular 5: Angular 5 app not rendered on iphone 5

Tags: javascript, angular, iphone-5

I am trying to run my angular app locally, it runs on all PCs and mobiles except iphone 5 and iphone 5s, it shows a white screen.

`index.html` is loaded but app component is not rendered
I have tried changing polyfills but didn't get result.

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: mmm ..maybe the browser doen't support it .. try to debug it with open browser console .. to check if are there any errors .. you can do it with inspect (your iphone cable ti your pc)

Comment: So how do you run it locally on iPhone? Do you test actual physical device or you emulate it somehow, let say in browser? Angular5 should has no issue with iPhone5 at all. It must be something in your code. Can you share some relevant code-related details?

Comment: @MirwaisAkrami if there is a minimal error in the html, angular2 displays a blank page, check browser compatibility

Comment: Do you use any device detection tools? Can you show us the rendered page source to confirm that app-root is not in the DOM or is empty?

Comment: @MirwaisAkrami - if there is any error in Angular the linter and the console would be red as a hell ...

Comment: I have hosted the app locally on my PC and using IP:port I am accessing it on other devices, it works fine on Samsung devices as well as IOS say Iphone 6, but on Iphone 5 and 5s, it doesnt show the app component

Comment: currently I dont have debugging tools for Iphone, but I have put some html in index, before app-root, and it displays it @Emocuc

Comment: And there is just empty app-root tag and no console error at all?

Comment: It might be something silly tiny. Are you sure that the iOS Safari on that device has javascript enabled?

Comment: @Emocuc, yes just white app-root tag, and I ran it on the chrome app of iphone 5 as well, but still no result

Comment: If other js apps work on that device and the app works on other devices, we need more code to see or to be able run the app -> can you share your repo (ie Git) or host it somewhere, so we can test it let say in BrowserStack?

Comment: Ok I will do something regarding it, thanks for your time @Emocuc

Comment: no worries, it sounds strange, I wonder what the issue might be ...

Comment: @MirwaisAkrami did you solved? How?